# Read the Garbage Collection (GC) configuration from external file in Java | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection

Running a spring boot jar file with the given GC configuration

- -Xloggc:/file/path/gc.log
- -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
- -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
- -XX:+PrintGCDetails

But, instead of passing all this GC information data in the command line when we are running the jar like

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=<env-name> -Xmx5G -Xms2G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:/file/path/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -jar application.jar
```

Is there any other approach that I can use to read the configuration from external file and pass it to jar

**Edit :**

As Slaw mentioned in the comment of using [java Command-Line Argument Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/java.html#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5)

Created a file with `args` as name & the data it has is

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=<env-name> -Xmx5G -Xms2G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -XX:+UseG1GC -Xloggc:/file/path/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -jar application.jar
```

by running the jar like

```
java @args
```

getting error as

```
Error: Could not find or load main class @args
```

It was not able to find the Main class. I think it was not identifying the jar in the `args` file.

Comment: Are you looking for [Command-Line Argument Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/java.html#GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111)?

Comment: @Slaw, yes. something like that. But, I'm getting an issue by using that approach. Will updated the question with that issue.

Comment: @Slaw updated the issue in the question

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If you look at the output of `java -help` do you see an _`@argument files`_ option?

Comment: `openjdk version "1.8.0_222"`. No I haven't saw any `@argument files` option in `java -help`

Comment: Then unfortunately you can't use argument files. I wasn't sure what version added that functionality, but Stephen's answer says Java 9. He also provides alternative solutions.

Comment: Yeah, saw the Stephen's answer. For now I will go with environment variable option. Thanks for your time @Slaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 9 and later, [command line argument files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/java.html#GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111) (`@file1`) *should* work<sup>1</sup>.

Another option for Java 9 and later is to set the [`JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__USINGTHEJDK_JAVA_OPTIONSLAUNCHERENV-F3C0E3BA) environment variable.  This gives a list of options that will be automatically prepended to the `java` command line's JVM options.

For Java 8 and earlier, your options are more limited:

- Write a shell wrapper script, shell function or shell alias for either the `java` command or your application's command line.
- Explicitly add an environment variable when you use the `java` command; e.g.

  ```
     $ java $STD_OPTS my.app.Main args ...
  ```
- You could conceivably implement a custom launcher (in C) an have that do clever things such as emulating Java 9's @file mechanism.

---

<sup>1 - Based on the symptoms, I think your attempt with `@file` failed either because the file was not found in the appropriate directory, or because you are using Java 8 or earlier.</sup>